# Select multiple highest nth values from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
EmpId   EmpName EmpJob      MGR     HireDate    Sal       Comm     Deptno

7369    SMITH   CLERK       7902    1980-12-17  1800.00   NULL      20
7499    ALLEN   SALESMAN    7698    1981-02-20  2600.00   300.00    30
7521    WARD    SALESMAN    7698    1981-02-22  2250.00   500.00    30
7566    JONES   MANAGER     7839    1981-04-02  3975.00   NULL      20
7654    MARTIN  SALESMAN    7698    1981-09-28  2250.00   1400.00   30
7698    BLAKE   MANAGER     7839    1981-05-01  3850.00   NULL      30
7782    CLARK   MANAGER     7839    1981-06-09  3450.00   NULL      10
7788    SCOTT   ANALYST     7566    1982-12-09  4000.00   NULL      20
```

In this table I am trying to find `5th` and `8th` `salary` and after that all the records `except` `5th` and `8th` record in single table. How can I get this result?

Comment: Tag the RDBMS you're using

Comment: Can You explain @GurwinderSingh

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Sql Server DB i am using . @GurwinderSingh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the window function Row_Number()

This will return all records.  5 & 8, followed by the remaining

```
Select *
 From (
        Select *
              ,RN = Row_Number() over (Order By Sal Desc)
         From  YourTable
      ) A
 Order by case when RN in (5,8) then 0 else 1 end,RN
```

**Note:** Switch to Dense_Rank() for ties

Comment: @RajanMishra Happy it helped